# Delete hash from end of the file

Tags: java, file, hash

I work with txt, png, jpeg, pdf files. And I make hash of file add at the end, but when I verify signature I have to delete that part, but I can not convert all bytes to String, because these different files have different encoding...

So is there any way to copy bytes to another file until I come to the last part which is in this form "Hash#" + hash of document in bytes..

I used code below but it works just for txt files.. Because when I write temp.getBytes() IN PNG DOC THAT ARE NOT SAME BYTES that are used to create this temp string, different files have differenet encoding..

```
while ((count2 = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                String temp = new String(buffer);
                if(temp.contains("Algoritam#")){...
```

Comment: A hash should have a fixed length, so just cut off the appropriate number of bytes?

Comment: Pleas do never convert binary data to a String like you do in `new String(buffer)`. Binary data is `byte[]` and should remain so. Only convert it to a String if you are 100% sure that the data contains human readable String data. Additionally adding data to the end of files can destroy the file so that it can't be read anymore unless you remove the appended data. Hashes are usually stored in a separate file, as you can create it e.g. using `sha256sum`.

Comment: Actually I have to use different algorithms for hashing so the length will not be the same always...

Answer (score 0):

You just read the contents of the file into a byte buffer with the size of `sizeOfYourFile - sizeOfTheHash`.